# Animation for ,Both end of circle moves in clockwisedirection

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to create a circular animation in IOS where both end of the circle increses , what it actually mean is one end increaes at slow speed and other end at high speed in both clockwise direction. So as to make the complete circle.

Comment: You can consider it as an arc moving to form the circle but the special thing is both of the end of the arc are moving , one with slow speed and one with high speed so the high speed end can catch the low speed end and can complete the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
-(CAShapeLayer *) createArcWithCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(CGFloat)radius
                           startAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endAngle
                           clockwise : (BOOL)clockwise duration :(CGFloat)duration
{
    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    circle.path = [UIBezierPath
                   bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius
                   startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle
                   clockwise:clockwise].CGPath;

    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    circle.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = 4;

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    animation.duration = duration;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fromValue = @(0);
    animation.toValue = @(1);
    animation.timingFunction=  [CAMediaTimingFunction
                                functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    [circle addAnimation:animation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

    return  circle;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    CGFloat startAngle = 0.0;
    CGFloat endAngle1  = M_PI * 2.0 / 2;
    CGFloat endAngle2 = M_PI * 2.0 - endAngle1;


    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(50, 50);
    CGFloat radius = 50;
    CGFloat duration = 6.0;

    UIView *circleView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, radius * 2 , radius * 2)];
    [self.view addSubview:circleView];

    CAShapeLayer *arc1 = [self
                          createArcWithCenter:center radius:radius
                          startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle1
                          clockwise:YES duration:duration];

    arc1.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

    CAShapeLayer *arc2 = [self
                          createArcWithCenter:center radius:radius
                          startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle2
                          clockwise:NO duration:duration];

    arc2.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

    [circleView.layer addSublayer:arc1];
    [circleView.layer addSublayer:arc2];
    //circleView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{

        int numberOfAnimations = 8;
        CGFloat durationPerAnimation = 1.0/numberOfAnimations;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAnimations; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%f",i*durationPerAnimation);
            [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:(i * durationPerAnimation) relativeDuration:durationPerAnimation animations:^{
                circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(circleView.transform, 3 * M_PI);
            }];
        }

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}
```

You can vary the `endAngle1` and `endAngle2` to vary the angles of each arc.

Comment: Thanks for the Code, but I need code for Objective C

Comment: converted to objectiveC @user1487846

Comment: I used the above code its not working correctly.

Comment: what is not working correctly? can you explain?

Comment: circle is not getting drawn correctly.

Comment: do you want to animate by starting in both clockwise and anticlockwise directions from a single point and completing the circle?

Comment: i have updated the code to do that.

Comment: what i exatly wants is, it starts with a dot ,then evolves as an incresing arc to make the circle.But the important thing is tale end of the arc slowly in clockwise direction and and head end start increasing in clockwise direction fastly. So that after some time it can catch the tale end after some time and circle gets completed.

Comment: did you check the updated code?

Comment: Yes i checked with that also, but it is also not working correctly.

Comment: Please find below the URL of the image, which will help you to understand my requiremnet. This are the two frames of the animation depcting progess of animation. Please check with them.                         http://i62.tinypic.com/iodw2d.jpg             http://i59.tinypic.com/m7xna9.png      http://i57.tinypic.com/bgwgg1.png

Comment: Great Job done. Almost near to the requiremnet. Just to increase speed and less no of rotation.

Comment: You can change the duration to change the speed.. And u can change numberofanimations value to change number of rotations

Comment: I checked at 4s in ios 7 and ios 8 the animation is not working correctly. Please update the code accordingly